# Observable.FromEvent doesn't complete

Tags: c#, system.reactive

```
var DeviceSubject = new Subject<NetworkEventArgs>();

Observable.FromEvent<EventHandler<NetworkEventArgs>, NetworkEventArgs>(h => Device.Connected += h, h => Device.Connected -= h)
.Subscribe(DeviceSubject);
```

The Device.Connected event is declared as follows...

```
public event EventHandler<NetworkEventArgs> Connected;
```

My MainForm_Load method stops executing after I call Observable.FromEvent.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "c#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `FromEventPattern`. The `FromEvent` is for non-standard events.

```
var DeviceSubject = new Subject<NetworkEventArgs>();

Observable
    .FromEventPattern<EventHandler<NetworkEventArgs>, NetworkEventArgs>(
        h => Device.Connected += h,
        h => Device.Connected -= h)
    .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs)
    .Subscribe(DeviceSubject);
```

Just as a side note: be careful using subjects like this. It's a common anti-pattern to do so. Any observable calling `OnComplete` into your subject can kill your code. It's better just to chain queries.

Comment: Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reactive.Subjects.Subject<NetworkEventArgs>' to 'System.IObserver<System.Reactive.EventPattern<NetworkEventArgs>>'

Comment: @TK3 - Sorry. Added the appropriate select.